# Allowing a single form to update 2 tables at once

Tags: python, django

I'm having a trouble where I want to use a form to update 2 different tables. My current form have a few variables. Hostname, ipaddr, mgmt, mgmtip etc. What I want to do now is take hostname, ipaddr and add into one table (This one done) and the other 2, mgmt and mgmtip to another table while under the same id. Like for example, hostname and ipaddr is registered under id of 1 (1st row of table 1) and mgmt and mgmtip to table 2 of the same id = 1. I am currently also able to extract the id for the 1st table. But I just cant seem to update the table2 under the same id.

Below is my code: In views.py

```
def device_add(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    device_frm = DeviceForm(request.POST) ##Part A1
    dd_frm = DeviceDetailForm()
    if device_frm.is_valid():
        device_frm.save()  ##Part A1
        deviceid = Device.objects.aggregate(Max('id')) ##Part A1 - Getting the ID of added device 
        device = Device.objects.all() ##Part A1
        if dd_frm.is_valid():
            dd_frm.save('id' == deviceid)
    return render(request, 'interface/device-added.html',{'devices':device})
       

else:
    device_frm = DeviceForm()
    dd_frm = DeviceDetailForm()
    di_frm = DeviceInterfaceForm()
    return render(request,'interface/device_add.html',{'form':device_frm, 'dd_form': dd_frm})
```

In models.py

```
class DeviceDetail(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mgt_interface = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mgt_ip_addr = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    subnetmask = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ssh_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ssh_pwd = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    enable_secret = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    device_model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.hostname
```

In forms.py

```
class DeviceDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= DeviceDetail
        fields= ['hostname', 'mgt_interface', 'mgt_ip_addr', 'subnetmask', 'ssh_id', 'ssh_pwd', 'enable_secret', 'device_model']
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(DeviceDetailForm, self).clean()
        hostname = cleaned_data.get('hostname')
        if len(hostname) < 8:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Hostname needs to be more than 8 character long, ' + hostname )
```

Comment: Can you share your `DeviceDetail` model?

Comment: as well as the `DeviceDetailForm`.

Comment: I have update the following as requested

Comment: why is `device_model` a `CharField`, and not a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: That is because within Device Model, user has to select a model given which the value inside is a string

Comment: but you can make a widget in the form to select this by name (see for example: https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you should not implement models to make a form cleaner, a model should focus on *storing* information in an efficient way and enforce constraints, a form should focus on how to ask the user for data.

Comment: Oh okay thanks ! I seem to get 'Exception Value: 
local variable 'device' referenced before assignment' for the code u provided and i cant figure out why

Comment: Fixed it but still doesnt seem to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to relative two tables together you must use relative fields in your model, like ForeignKey, ManyToManyField, and ...,

model:

```
class DeviceModel(Model.models):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ipaddr = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class DeviceDetailModel(Model.models):
    device = models.ForeignKey(DeviceModel, related_name='Device_Model', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mgmt = models.SOMEField
    mgmtip  = models.SOMEField
```

Form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import DeviceModel, DeviceDetailModel
    class DeviceForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = DeviceModel
            fields = '__all__'
    class DeviceDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
        mgmt = forms.SOMEField
        mgmtip  = forms.SOMEField
        class Meta:
            model = DeviceDetailModel
            fields = '__all__'
```

and now

```
if request.method == "POST":
    device_frm = DeviceForm(request.POST)
    dd_frm = DeviceDetailForm(request.POST)
    if device_frm.is_valid():
        device_frm.save()  ##Part A1
        deviceid = Device.objects.aggregate(Max('id')) 
        device = Device.objects.all() ##Part A1
        if dd_frm.is_valid():
            deviceD = dd_frm.save(commit=False)
            deviceD.device = Device.objects.get(id=deviceid)
            deviceD.save()
    return render(request, 'interface/device-added.html',{'devices':device})
```

P.S: you forget to add `request.POST` to `dd_frm = DeviceDetailForm(request.POST)`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder :) I updated my code and follow this but it doesn't seem to save

Comment: it works for me, and I will so thanks full if you vote for me and accept me

Comment: Hello, can u explain the code of this 2 lines? deviceD = dd_frm.save(commit=False) &
deviceD.device = Device.objects.get(id=deviceid)

Comment: in DeviceDetailModel we have device ForeignKey but in DeviceDetailForm we dont have that, but in DeviceDetailForm Meta class, in fields, we add all of DeviceDetailModel fields, now in our form we only need mgmt and mgmtip to get from client and you must add device by yourself, you do deviceD = dd_frm.save(commit=False), now you can add  device (infact after commit false you have all of fields you added in Class Meta of From) or in another project if you have S.Th you don't want to get that from client S.Th like date of you create that data or user who create this in model and you have form

Answer (score 0):

Your model should work with a `ForeignKey` or `OneToOneField` to refer to the device it is linked to, so:

```
class DeviceDetail(models.Model):
    # …
    device_model = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In your form, you should return the cleaned data after validation, so:

```
class DeviceDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= DeviceDetail
        fields= ['hostname', 'mgt_interface', 'mgt_ip_addr', 'subnetmask', 'ssh_id', 'ssh_pwd', 'enable_secret', 'device_model']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        hostname = cleaned_data.get('hostname')
        if len(hostname) < 8:
            raise forms.ValidationError(f'Hostname needs to be more than 8 character long, {hostname}')
        return cleaned_data
```

or cleaner:

```
class DeviceDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= DeviceDetail
        fields= ['hostname', 'mgt_interface', 'mgt_ip_addr', 'subnetmask', 'ssh_id', 'ssh_pwd', 'enable_secret', 'device_model']

    def clean_hostname(self):
        hostname = self.cleaned_data['hostname']
        if len(hostname) < 8:
            raise forms.ValidationError(f'Hostname needs to be more than 8 character long, {hostname}')
        return hostname
```

You can set the `.device_model_id` with the primary key of the altered device with:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    device_frm = DeviceForm(request.POST)
    dd_frm = DeviceDetailForm(request.POST)
    if device_frm.is_valid() and dd_from.is_valid():
        device = device_frm.save()
        if dd_frm.is_valid():
            dd_frm.instance.device_model = device
            dd_frm.save()
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.